# Mongo New Replica Set Old Data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have MongoDB replica set (3 servers) running on AWS.  Every 6 hours I take a snapshot of the volume.

I have the need to get off Amazon Linux 1 and move to Ubuntu Linux due to some package changes.  I have turned off the old cloudformation stack, created a new cloudformation stack using Ubuntu and now everything is blank.

So now, I take my snapshot, create a volume, remove the volume currently on the EC2, attach the new volume with old data, run `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data` and `sudo chmod -R go+w /data` and then restart Mongodb `sudo systemctl restart mongod`

This does start, but in the mongo log, I get this issue:

"msg":"Heartbeat failed after max retries","attr":{"target":"db2.ospreynrglive.com:27017","maxHeartbeatRetries":2,"error":{"code":93,"codeName":"InvalidReplicaSetConfig","errmsg":"replica set IDs do not match, ours: 604d72257a07ddd82163de70; remote node's: 604e566ee4290c91c30c91c3ff6504"}}}

How can I fix this?  I try to edit local.system.replset and that doesn't work.  Tried to specify the replicaSetId in rs initialize which failed and also rs.reconfig won't let me change it either.

I know that I can do a mongodump and mongorestore but this is extremely slow when having lots of data.  Can I not use the data/volume/backup/snapshot from AWS?  What would happen if all 3 servers went down at the same time on AWS?  I would be in the same situation!

Comment: Start first mongod as single node (with that data) (not as RS). When it's running, do 'rs.initiate()'. Then node by node rs.add().

Answer (score -1):

Anyone looking to clear an existing Replica Set needs to do the following steps:

Start mongod without --replSet flag

Run this on mongo shell

```
use admin
db.grantRolesToUser("admin", [{ role: "__system", db: "admin" }])
use local
db.dropDatabase()
use admin
db.revokeRolesFromUser("admin", [{ role: "__system", db: "admin" }])
```

Then restart mongod with --replSet flag and it will be like no RS was ever initiated

From here, you initiate it on the primary and then do the same with the other nodes and add each one.